# Etymology of the word "sauce" in context of steroids

Tags: etymology, sports

The word "sauce" is used when talking about steroids, but I cannot figure out why. I have been trying to find why it is called this way on the Internet and have been looking for similar meanings in dictionaries but I couldn't find out the origins. Can anybody help me to find information about it?

Here is an example of the usage of [sauce](https://www.google.ru/books/edition/Building_Bodies/k1uD3rGvUbEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=sauce+steroids&pg=PA198&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: I voted to close this answer as a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/607339/etymology-of-slang-term-for-steroids-juice because the latter version of the question was posted slightly earlier than this one. However, the answer posted here by TaliesinMerlin should (in my opinion) be transferred to the other version of the question, if possible.